# How to call keypress event in span tags inside contenteditable true div in vuejs / vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs2

I am trying to create an editor in vue.js which has the structure like this.

This is the code snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ContentEditable problem in vue.js</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="editor"
             contenteditable="true"
             class="form-control"
             style="height: 200px; overflow-y: auto">
            <!-- @input="update($event,anyBlock)" if I put this inside the div tag it will call update method-->

            <span @input="update($event,block1)">
                <!-- This update method is not getting called
                If we make this span tag contenteditable true and
                put it inside a contenteditable false tag(say a span tag) it will work
                But It will not give you feel like an editor, so please avoid that solution.-->
                    {{ block1.text }}
            </span>
            <span @input="update($event,block2)">
                <!-- Not need to say. This has similar problem-->
                    {{ block1.text }}
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <pre>
        {{ $data }}
    </pre>
</div>

</body>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.8/vue.min.js'></script>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el:'.container',
        data:{
            block1: {
                id: '1',
                type: 'text',
                text: 'Edit me id :1!'
            },
            block2: {
                id: '2',
                type: 'text',
                text: 'Edit me id :2!'
            }
        },
        methods: {
            update: function (event, block) {
                console.dir(event)
                if (block.id === '1') {
                    this.block1.text = event.target.innerText
                    // If you call this function from div the whole text is going to be copied inside the div.
                } else {
                    this.block2.text = event.target.innerText
                }
            }
        }

    })
</script>
</html>
```

But as usual ***the keypress, keydown, keyup events are captured in the div*** because it is contenteditable.

I don't want to use

```
<span contenteditable="false">
         <span contenteditable="true">
                 {{block1.text}}
         </span>
</span>
<span contenteditable="false">
         <span contenteditable="true">
                 {{block2.text}}
         </span>
</span>
```

Because this blocks the free cursor movement inside the editor.

What will be the best possible solution for my problem?

Comment: Could you use JSFiddle to demonstrate this? I'm not really clear what the problem is and what you're trying to do

Comment: @anthonygore Are you familiar with vue js?

Comment: It seems like what you need is model binding to the inner text/html of an HTML tag. And I believe this is not possible with Vue (as it stands right now)
You might not be able to start with the values `{{block1.text}}`, but instead have to assign it (on mount when the component loads) to the element innerHTML.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, now that I understand your predicament better, let me see if I can rephrase the problem:

- You're using a `contenteditable` `div` to change the styling on the fly for a quasi-WYSIWYG input field
- The `div` swallows events from the child elements
- You would also like to keep an eye on events from specific spans

And now for some of what I found while trying to solve your problem:

- Trying to use v-model on a `contenteditable` `div` results in this warning (Vue 2.1.8): `[Vue warn]: v-model is not supported on element type: <div>. If you are working with contenteditable, it's recommended to wrap a library dedicated for that purpose inside a custom component.`
- Contenteditable wrapper: https://jakiestfu.github.io/Medium.js/docs/ (which Evan You, creator of Vue mentions here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1670)
- Contenteditable events: http://codebits.glennjones.net/editing/events-contenteditable.htm

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to figure out the exact answer you were looking for - that is, I couldn't figure out how to get a Vue event to fire from a `DOMNodeElement` in a `contenteditable` `div`. What I did instead was this terribly hacky solution wherein I watch the contents of the div with a `ref` and then render each line as a `span` element and shove it back into the `div` on two events: `blur`, or changing the focus outside of the div, and a specific keypress (meta + enter).

You can see that here: https://jsfiddle.net/briankung/9fpg40q0/1/

Unfortunately, I don't know exactly what you're going for, but this is my best attempt at 1am. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks for this. But I don't really want to use external libraries. I have reformatted the question I hope this helps now. I will accept your answer, you are really close to solve it.